# Connections won't go past the gateway router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, troubleshooting, network-adapter

Oh boy, I don't even know how to begin looking into this. Essentially:

```
$ tracepath -n 8.8.8.8
1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
1:  192.168.177.1                                         0.506ms 
1:  192.168.177.1                                         0.451ms 
2:  192.168.177.1                                         0.462ms reached
    Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 2 back 1
```

The effect is that I cannot reach any ressource in the web (for example `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` for HTTP requests). I can still connect to ressources in the local network though.

Naturally I suspected something was up with the router first (unfortunately i don't have admin access to it) **but** other machines connected through the same box can still reach the internet just fine. *However* on this machine, the issue persists independent of OS, both on Linux and Windows (first occured on Windows in the middle of a session out of the blue).

I'm at a total loss here. What can cause such behavior? Is it maybe hardware related? Where can I look and what information should I provide for further diagnosis?

Comment: Can you see if a machine that normally works still works when attached to the same port/physical connection?

Comment: Tried it, no difference. Would have been surprising though. I have 3 machines (1 of which is the faulty one) connected to a 5 port switch, which is connected to yet another switch that is connected to the router.

Comment: Might the admin have blocked your MAC address?  The 'connection refused' message is odd for a lack of connectivity problem; one would expect something more along the line of a "connection timed out" or a "No route to host" error.

Comment: wow thanks, spoofing the MAC does indeed solve the issue. Looks like I'm gonna have a chat with the admin tomorrow. Maybe it's a social problem, not a technical one...